# XMLHttpRequest automatically replaces backslash (\) with slash (/)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to run a small javascript script. one of the parameters of the XMLHttpRequest is a file path, so a URL would look like:

```
http://myaddress:myport/action/C:\\PATH\\TO\\MY\\FILE.EXT/some/other/params
```

however, XMLHttpRequest changes the address to:

```
http://myaddress:myport/action/C://PATH//TO//MY//FILE.EXT/some/other/params
```

which breaks the application. How can I prevent XMLHttpRequest from changing the requested address?

Comment: You really send up a path? So any hacker can retrieve any file off of the server? Yikes

Comment: That is just for a test in my local computer, a proof of concept if you will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put raw special characters in the URL.

```
encodeURIComponent('C:\\PATH\\TO\\MY\\FILE.EXT')
"C%3A%5CPATH%5CTO%5CMY%5CFILE.EXT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the path before putting it into your URL:

```
'http://myaddress:myport/action/' + encodeURIComponent('C:\\PATH\\TO\\MY\\FILE.EXT') + '/some/other/params'
```