# Reading a XML present in different path using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an XML file named **Vehicle.xml** in location "C:\Documents and Settings\Nabajyot\Desktop".

I want to read the xml file by using jquery.

How to do it???

I am using the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get("C:\Documents and Settings\Nabajyot\Desktop\Vehicle.xml", {}, function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('Vehicle').each(function (i) {
            alert($(this).find("Type").text());
        });
    });

});
```

But its not Working...

Please Help me out.

Comment: Some browsers restrict what you can do with files on your local system for security reasons. Your best solution is to run a local web server -- this is not difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a local web server and put your xml file there. Then access it by `http://localhost/path-to-your-file.xml`

OR

You can upload it somewhere and use that URL.

EDIT: for example: http://filebin.ca/

Comment: Thank uou Lian for your reply. 
If i upload to a document library of a sharepoint site and read it in newForm.aspx. is it possible???

Answer (score 0):

You can't load a file from your local filesystem, like this, you need to put it on a a web server like apache www directory or htdocs folder and load it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape the path you have hardcoded e.g. [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Some examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944251/xmlhttprequest-automatically-replaces-backslash-with-slash